# JQuery .ajaxStart not being called

Tags: jquery

I am using the JQuery 1.7.2 and am trying to have an 'isDirty' flag throw a confirm message to the user if an ajax call is made.  If the user clicks ok the ajax call should happen and if they cancel the confirm message the ajax call should not happen and leave the user on the page.  I have the following function on my page

```
...
$(function() {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        if (isDirty) {
            var status = confirm('You have unsaved changes! Are you sure you want to continue?');
            if (status) {
                isDirty = false;
            }
            return status;
        }
        return true;
    });
...
});
```

and the .ajaxStart is never being called.  If I replace .ajaxStart with .AjaxSend it is called, but if I cancel the confirm and 'false' is returned from the function it loads the ajax request anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Create an AJAX query and immediately cancel it is not a good idea. You should make your test before creating AJAX query.

I suggest you to create a custom AJAX function, wrappring the jQuery one, where you could check your flag and launch the query after user confirmation.

```
var ajaxSecure = function() {
  if (isDirty) {
    var status = confirm('You have unsaved changes! Are you sure you want to continue?');
    if (status) {
      isDirty = false;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return $.ajax(arguments);
};
```

And then use your ajaxSecure() instead of $.ajax().